# How to efficiently map between an existing array and a result of query Collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array containing several objects with keys initialized to `0` except for the first key in each object which is initialized to certain date:

```
$data = [];

for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    $data[] = (object)['main_key' => DateTime formatted string, 'key1' => '0', 'key2' => '0'];
}
```

I also have a query that groups by main_key and returns a result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
  #items: array:4 [
    0 => {
      +"main_key": 2022-05
      +"key1": "some_value"
      +"key2": "some_value"
    }
    1 => {
      +"date": 2022-05
      +"key1": "some_value"
      +"key2": "some_value"
    }
    2 => {
      +"date": 2022-04
      +"key1": "some_value"
      +"key2": "some_value"
    }
    3 => {
      +"date": 2022-03
      +"key1": "some_value"
      +"key2": "some_value"
    }
  ]
```

How can I efficiently map the values so that the values of key1 and key2 will be set in the correct date? (They have the same number of objects)

Comment: If you'd prepare the source arrays accordingly, you could use a `foreach` loop + a lookup via `isset()` into the other array... arrange the lookup array, so that the key you're looking for becomes the index of the array. Otherwise, you'd have to use two nested loops

Comment: thank you, that was what I was thinking about. I just thought there might be some more efficient way :)